# How to get around this CORS issue using axios?

Tags: api, reactjs, cors, axios

I'm trying to redo the Random Quote Generator challenge from freecodecamp using React. When I make an API request to Forismatic using axios, I can't fetch any data.

A look into the browser console shows that I'm having a CORS issue. How do I get around this issue? Keep in mind, I did the exact same project using jQuery and didn't have any problems connecting the API.

```
const url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?";

    axios.get(url).then((data) => {

      console.log(data); // No response
    })
```

Comment: I found this issue on github might help you out. https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/113